# I am trying to understand the arguments in __init__ and function in below code

Tags: python

Here I am trying to understand how perform_math_task is defined and how it is being accessed later on with add function.

```
class Human():
    def __init__(self, name, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender

    def speak_name(self):
        print "My name is %s" % self.name

    def speak(self, text):
        print text

    def perform_math_task(self, math_operation, *args):
        print "%s is champion in mathmatic operation %f" %(self.name, math_operation(*args))

def add (a, b):
        return a+b

will = Human("XYZ", "Female")

print will.name
print will.gender

will.speak_name
will.speak("I love Python Programming.")
will.perform_math_task(add, 34, 67)
```

Comment: If you want to get an answer, you must ask a _specific_ question.  So, what is your question?

Comment: I want to know how argument variables are passed to the method " perform_math_task". And separately defined an add function. Later then accessed it. Basically, i am trying to understand below lines:

def perform_math_task(self, math_operation, *args):
will.perform_math_task(add, 34, 67)    //here the add method used as the argument to the other method.

Comment: This question is way **too broad** since you aren't asking a specific question. You are just asking us to explain all the code.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__(self, name, gender)` intializes name = "XYZ" and  gender = "Female" `perform_math_task(self, math_operation, *args)` takes the first argument add as math_operation and 34 and 67 as *args.
So `math_operation(*args)` is actually `add(*args)` or `add(34, 67)`